# Android ratingbar with tablelayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am using TableLayout in my application with 4 columns. When I insert a rating bar in a row, with `layout_span=3`, the stars are not working as expected.

For Example, I gave `numStars=5`, but it is showing **2/3** of 6th star. Also if I click on 3rd star, it selects 3.25 stars, if select 4th, 4.5 is highlighted and so on ... the scaling is not working properly.

I tried changing layout_height to wrap_content, but same result. Only if I delete layout_span, then it works fine, but in that case my columns of other rows have distortion.

Can anyone please help me regarding what is the issue? And if this is the normal behavior, then how can I get proper rating bar with layout_span?

```
<TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/rating" />

        <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/add_rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:stepSize="1"
                android:rating="4" />

    </TableRow>
// NORMAL ROW
<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lab_datepurchased"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/datepurchased" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/add_datepurchased"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/dateinput" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lab_shelfno"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/shelfno" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/add_shelfno"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/definputtext2" />

        </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/banner_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="rating" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/add_rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="1"
            android:rating="4" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lab_datepurchased"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/datepurchased" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_datepurchased"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/dateinput" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lab_shelfno"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/shelfno" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_shelfno"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/definputtext2" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: sorry, but I totally lost it. Can you kindly explain? I need only one rating bar in a single row. other rows are normal (I edited my initial post to show one sample normal row)

Comment: WHat is happening, the 3rd column of 2nd row starts after the end of ratingbar (the reason that I used layout_span) ... hence there is a huge gap between 2nd and 3rd column of 2nd row.

Comment: It's not huge gap becz we gave equal weight to all 4 views so weight is equali divide not size of view content

Comment: oh ya, my mistake ... now it's working fine, thanks ... btw, I just changed your code for 2nd row to put 1st and 3rd column with fixed width 80dp, and 2nd and 4th column with weighted width, now I can control the gap.